# Installing R packages. Include directory is empty. Development headers

Tags: r, unix

I am currently trying to run some R code that originally ran under 2.11.0 . The version of R that I am using 2.14.1 does not run the code. I am unfamiliar with R and how backwards compatible it is. (My issue could have nothing to do versions for all I know; I will be happy to learn that it is something that I am doing wrong.) The rest of the code is irrelevant; my installs are failing even when I run by themselves.

```
#these fail
install.packages("gtools",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
install.packages("minet", repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
#these work
install.packages("psych", repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
install.packages("qvalue",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
install.packages("R2HTML",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
```

I have tried other installation methods in addition to the one I listed above. I have tried installing and compiling earlier versions of gtools and minet. I have tried getting current versions of the package from other repos (biocLite). However all installation attempts produce identical failures. For a little more background, I am not a superuser on the machine that I am trying to run this code on. I can ask the person who is the superuser for small favors (ones that do not affect other users of the machine). I have been able to install other packages just fine; though as I said early if I have a simple problem I will be pleased. Here are some failures.

```
* installing *source* package ‘gtools’ ...
** libs
Warning: R include directory is empty -- perhaps need to install R-devel.rpm or similar
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c setTCPNoDelay.c -o setTCPNoDelay.o
setTCPNoDelay.c:1:15: error: R.h: No such file or directory
setTCPNoDelay.c:2:24: error: Rinternals.h: No such file or directory
setTCPNoDelay.c: In function ‘checkStatus’:
setTCPNoDelay.c:66: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strncpy’
setTCPNoDelay.c:66: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
setTCPNoDelay.c:72: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror’
setTCPNoDelay.c:72: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strncpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
make: *** [setTCPNoDelay.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gtools’
```

Comment: You need the R headers to be able to compile against them ("need to install R-devel.rpm or similar").

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  
How would I go about getting said headers and where would I put them?

Comment: that depends on your OS and how it's setup.  Ask the person who installed R on it to install the development headers as well.

Comment: Why are you installing source in the first place?  Do you really have an OS for which CRAN doesn't have binaries?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Installing the source is just one of methods that I have used to try and install the above packages. All attempts fails in a manner similar to the one stated above. I am not trying to be particular about install packages--I just want to find some method that works. I believe that the packages I want may have some compatibility issue with R, since earlier versions of R are able to load the mentioned packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error arose because the particular machine that i was logged into did not have the development headers. My system admin directed me to login into a different machine that did. What was rather odd about this is that R would allow me to install some packages without the headers. If you intermittently get this complaint when attempting to install R packages, it may have to do with the development headers as Joshua Ulrich mention in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the fact gcc cannot find "R.h" on the default include paths (/usr/local/include), etc.

In root mode, it can be solved easily by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

In user mode, it can be solved by downloading and compiling your own copy of the code:

```
wget "https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.2.tar.gz"
tar xvfz R-3.2.2.tar.gz
cd R-3.2.2
./configure --prefix=/SOME_LOCAL_DIR
make; make install
```

Now launch R specifying the path of the include dir (where R.h can be found):

```
export CPATH=/LOCAL_PATH/R-3.2.2/include/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/LOCAL_PATH/R-3.2.2/include/
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/LOCAL_PATH/R-3.2.2/include/
export GCC_INCLUDE_DIR=/LOCAL_PATH/R-3.2.2/include/
./bin/R
```

Now install.packages() should work properly

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")
```