# R include directory is empty

Tags: linux, r, redhat

I have RedHat 6.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) running `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)`.

As explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950437/installing-r-packages-include-directory-is-empty-development-headers), some packages install fine, while others produce the warning "R include directory is empty -- perhaps need to install R-devel.rpm or similar". When this warning appears, I also get `make: gcc: Command not found` and the package fails to compile.

The answer is apparently to install the "development headers", but I am not sure what this means. The accepted answer does not explain it.

I tried `sudo yum install R-devel`, but I get some errors related to dependencies.

```
Error: Package: rstudio-0.95.265-1.x86_64 (@oit-el-6-x86_64/6.3)
       Requires: libRblas.so()(64bit)
       Removing: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (@oit-stable-epel-x86_64-6)
           libRblas.so()(64bit)
       Updated By: R-core-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 (oit-testing-epel-x86_64-6)
           Not found
       ...

Error: Package: rstudio-0.95.265-1.x86_64 (@oit-el-6-x86_64/6.3)
       Requires: libRlapack.so()(64bit)
       Removing: R-core-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (@oit-stable-epel-x86_64-6)
           libRlapack.so()(64bit)
       Updated By: R-core-3.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 (oit-testing-epel-x86_64-6)
           Not found
       ...
```

I'm not sure what this means. New to Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that [other folks were having trouble with the same dependencies](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201046993-Library-dependency-issue-on-Fedora-20-), so I uninstalled RStudio then reinstalled the latest version. To get the newest version of R, I configured yum to use EPEL.

`su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'`

Then I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277953/install-r-3-on-redhat-6-3) to re-install R.

`su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'`

This enabled me to install packages that need to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I may add that the updated EPEL and version corresponding to your Linux version can be found here:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

The `su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'` command really solved the "R include directory is empty" issue. However, for me it required to allow yum to enable disabled repositories. Can be done by editing the file `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf` e.g. using `sudo nano search-disabled-repos.conf`